# Ram errors, shows correct size but in memtest shows only limited size

Tags: linux, ram

I have a 2 ddr3 pairs of unmatched ram. Pair 1 is 4GB 1333Mhz. Pair 2 is 8GB 1600Mhz. In memtest, the total shows 12GB, but when i check the memory mappings in the dmi memory device info , it shows that pair 2 only is 1G in size each.

Other symptoms include transfer over usb freezes the computer. When using the problematic ram, pair 2, the machine doesn't even POST, but with the other ram in as first, the machine works fine.

RMA? Or try pair 2 on another computer?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is good idea to check your RAM on different computer. Also check logs if something is disabled/error on BIOS. You can use `dmidecode` or `lshw` to get more details on hardware.

Comment: dmidecode and lshw is only going to show the data that is embedded within the device. From the dmi memory mapping page in memtest, it clearly shows only 1G is mapped into the virtual memory space, even though it says the ram is 4G in size.

I've also been getting something from the kernel:

ata16.00: exception emask 0x1 Sact serr 0x0 action 0x6
ata16.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
... Mode Sense(6) .... ( HSM violation )

Makes no sense to me since i don't have a hsm or tpm attached anywhere

Comment: humm, in that case you should try on different computer.